# Para que serve o operador ~ (til) no PHP?

Tags: php, operadores, bit

Para que serve o operador `~` (til) no PHP?

Já vi coisas como:

```
echo ~PHP_INT_MAX
```

Até então eu pensava que era para "inverter" um número para negativo, ou alguma coisa do tipo, mas com os testes vi que eu estava enganado.

Exemplo:

```
echo ~2; //Imprime -3

echo ~5; //Imprime -6
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

É o operador de negação *bit* a *bit*. Ou seja, ele inverte o valor de todos os *bits* do dado em questão. Os que eram 0 viram 1 e os que eram 1 viram 0. O nome dele é [*bitwise not*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). Não confundir com o operador lógico de negação `!`.

Ele não negativa o número, para isto existe o operador unário de negativo.

Então o número 2 pode ser representado em binário por

```
00000010 //isto é 2 em binário
```

negando (invertendo) os *bits* fica:

```
11111101 //isto é -3 em binário
```

Fiz com 8 *bits* para simplificar, provavelmente o número teria mais *bits*. Se transformar este número para decimal, obterá o tal do -3.

Se analisar, o 2 é o terceiro número dos positivos, e o 3 também é o terceiro número dos negativos. Há uma inversão neste sentido, mas o fato de ir do positivo para o negativo é uma questão do tipo de dado.

A utilidade dele é bem grande em alguns cenários, mas a maioria dos programadores não conseguem enxergar quando ele pode ser usado para evitar matemáticas mirabolantes. O simples muitas vezes é mais difícil de enxergar.

Quando você vê isto:

```
E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE
```

Lê assim: liga todos os erros ALL, mas NÃO os erros que seja `STRICT`, também NÃO os `WARNING` e também NÃO os `NOTICE`. Isto é uma expressão que vai resultar em um número que será usado adequadamente pelo PHP para entender o que está ligado ou não. O humano entende da forma como eu mostrei, mas para selecionar, o código tratará dos *bits* existentes em combinação apropriada.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).