# Qual é a regra para converter um valor binário para um número negativo e vice-versa?

Tags: string, conversão-de-tipo, inteiros, números-binários

Fiquei com uma dǘvida depois que o [@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101) respondeu a essa pergunta:

[Para que serve o operador ~ (til) no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77924/para-que-serve-o-operador-til-no-php)

Como é possível obter o valor negativo em binário?

E como, através do binário, chegar a um valor negativo?

Na resposta do @Maniero, ele explicou que `11111101` é igual a `-3`.

Porque quando faço a conversão, me é retornado `253`.

```
var_dump(bindec('11111101')); Imprime 253
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lembrando que ali eu usei um exemplo de 8 bits que bem falou o mgibsonbr, não é a forma que o PHP monta números. Isto faz toda a diferença porque ele precisará fazer alinhamento de dados e vai gerar um número diferente do esperado por causa da posição do sinal.

Se você quer realmente garantir que o primeiro bit do que enviar seja o sinal, até onde eu sei, só dá para fazer manualmente. A [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php#90142) tem um exemplo:

```
function bin2si($bin, $bits = 32) { 
    if (strlen($bin) == $bits) { 
        if (substr($bin, 0, 1) == 0) { // positive or zero 
            $si = base_convert($bin, 2, 10); 
        } else { // negative 
            $si = base_convert($bin, 2, 10); 
            $si = -(pow(2, $bits) - $si); 
        } 
        return $si; 
    } 
} 

echo bin2si('11111101', 8);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/y8WJmw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/avluyspz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/Bin2Si.php).

Comment: Uma curiosidade: Por que o nome da função é `bin2si`? O que seria esse `si`?

Comment: `signed integer`.

Answer (score 5):

Os números negativos - pelo menos para o tipo inteiro - são normalmente representados pelo [complemento de dois](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_para_dois). Isso significa que o dígito mais significativo é que determina se o número será positivo ou negativo. `11111101` só é considerado negativo se você estiver trabalhando com uma precisão de 8 bits (já que o 8º bit é `1`).

Entretanto, um inteiro em PHP não tem só 8 bits, normalmente tem 32 (mas depende da plataforma). Então, `11111101` na verdade seria:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 11111101
```

Que é igual a `253`. Assumindo uma precisão de 32 bits, `-3` é igual a:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101
```

Como o número de `1`s à esquerda depende da precisão, não dá pra fazer isso de forma confiável só aumentando o número de `1`s (o `bindec`, aliás, [converte o número pra ponto flutuante se ele for grande demais pra caber num inteiro](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.bindec.php)). Mas se você souber/especificar a precisão, então o método da [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78343/215) é suficiente para fazer essa conversão de forma correta.